# How is Model::find($id) secure in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have an app where I create entries based on who is signed in. If I use the `find($id)` method it returns `json` response. The function is like this:

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $chore = Chore::find($id);
        return response()->json($chore);
    }
```

Now if I where to edit the id value I might be able to access other user's data which isn't secure at all.
So I added and extra column `user_id` that checks who is signed in:

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $chore = Chore::find($id)
        ->where('user_id', Auth::id());
        return response()->json($chore);
    }
```

But of course laravel can't make it easy so it doesn't work. Adding `->get()` returns an array instead of a json response.
First of all how is `find($id)` ever secure in any app that uses authentication and secondly how do I add another condition under the `find($id)` clause? I need data returned in `JSON` otherwise I will need to rewrite all my front-end which isn't ideal at this point.

I also tried:

```
 public function edit($id)
    {
        $chore = Chore::where('id', $id)
        ->where('user_id', Auth::id());
        return response()->json($chore);
    }
```

but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call the `where` method before the `find` method

```
$chore = Chore::where('user_id', Auth::id())
    ->find($id);
```

As an alternative, If you've set up relationships properly on user model

```
// In User.php
public function chores()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Chore::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

then you could also do

```
$chore = Auth::user()->chores()->find($id);
```

While this seems like extra work, it's more convenient and easier to maintain.

Comment: Yeah, this works! I don't have relationships setup on Users but I might do it. I wasn't planning deleting users but hmm, maybe ...

Answer (score 1):

If Chore is in a one-to-one relationship with your User model, then you can create a relationship in your `User.php` model.

```
public function chore() {
    return $this->hasOne(Chore::class);
}
```

Then in your controller, you could simply call `auth()->user()->chore`.

The Eloquent's `find()` method finds only one record by the primary key. If you use additional validation it's perfectly safe. You could use route model binding to simplify the code.

web.php

```
Route::get('/chore/{chore}/', 'ChoreController@edit');
```

Then in your controller

```
public function edit(Chore $chore)
{
   if (! $chore->user_id === auth()->id()) {
     // throw error or redirect, or whetever
   }

   return response()->json($chore);
}
```

To simplify the controller a little bit more, you could create a form request and inject it into controller's method as a regular request. (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#authorizing-form-requests)

Then you could move the validation into your form request. It should look something like this:

```
    public function authorize() {
        return $this->route('chore')->user_id === $this->user()->id
    }
```